# Map interactions not working when event starts on a marker [Mapbox]

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I've got a Mapbox map working with custom markers.  I've got an issue in that when I'm interacting with the map, regardless of type (zoom, pan, tilt etc) and number of fingers used, if one finger starts on a marker then that event will not work.  The marker click listener doesn't get called, so it seems that the marker isn't consuming the event.  I'd added logging to the other event listeners on the Mapbox view and none of them are being called either (`OnCameraChangeListener`, `OnMapClickListener`, `OnScrollListener`, `OnFlingListener` etc)

Debug mode on the Mapbox view is enabled.

The problem is that we have a lot of markers in a very small area, and it's almost impossible to manipulate the map.

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a fix for this, you can track the [progress here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5388). One thing to note is that the fix most likely will break a few APIs in the SDK which means the fix won't make it till the 5.0 release of the Mapbox Android SDK. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this - do you have a ETA for the 5.0 release?

Comment: It's currently on our timeline after the 4.2.0 final release (this could always change however)